# SVG in uiWebView - in swift

Tags: ios, svg, uiwebview, uiimageview

I want to display SVG Image in my project. So I used `UIWebView` to showcase it.

I drag & drop an SVG image to my project & i used this code & its worked for me.

```
 var path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("page_6", ofType: "svg")!
 var url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

But now i want to use path as '/Users/bri/Downloads/case_out/svg/page_6'. So I want to use like this

```
var path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("/Users/bridgelabz/Downloads/case_out/svg/page_5", ofType: "svg")!`
```

But obviously image is not present in main `bundle()` so its giving me an error. So my question is that Is there any way available by which i can access an image through local path & display an `UIImageView`?

Comment: Are you making a OSX app or an iOS app?

Comment: What you are trying to do is access the local file in your computer from your simulator, which is not possible. Your app run on a sandbox environment, and it can only access assets in its own sandbox folders.

Comment: Basically i have one zip file & i am unzipping it & saving it in simulators home directory now i want to retrieve that image from simulators home directory. Is it possible to retrieve an image from simulators home directory?

Comment: Nope, you can only access file in your app sandbox directory or from a web service.

Comment: Any idea ? what i can do in such a situation ?

Comment: Like what you did in the first place, add it to your project

Comment: In first I have to call an URL then i need download zip file which i then unzip &  i want to just display this .svg image into uiwebview